Application.OnKey procedure not available when .xlsm opened from Sharepoint Online
I'm using Application.OnKey to intercept attempts to use Ctrl + X and Ctrl + V to cut and paste all, and instead notify the user that they must instead use Ctrl + C and then Ctrl + Alt + V to open 'Paste Special' and select 'Values'. This is to avoid the problems that standard Paste All brings with it, i.e. pasting everything including data validation, formatting, etc.
Calls to the ToggleCut and TogglePaste procedures are made, with a Boolean parameter to allow/disallow cut/paste, from various workbook-level and sheet-level events, according to whether the system admin is logged in, or whether the active sheet is a 'user sheet' (i.e. fully unlocked sheet for side calcs and reference material).
These calls work perfectly when the workbook is opened from local storage, i.e. somewhere on the user's computer. But if the workbook is opened using 'Open in app' in a Sharepoint Online document library, despite all other macro code in the VBA project being available and functional, the procedure associated with the keyboard shortcuts is reported as not available.
Here's the message that appears when the file is opened from Sharepoint and you try using Ctrl + V, for example:

Cannot run the macro "https://[Sharepoint site URL][long chain of subdirectories to file][filename.xlsm]'!". The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.

I note that the message indicates that no macro is associated with the keyboard shortcut, hence the ! after the filename followed by nothing... however, I added a breakpoint in the Workbook_Open procedure just before the calls to toggle cut/paste on/off, and stepped through it upon opening the file from Sharepoint... the code is definitely being run.
If blAdminModeEnabled Or Left$(wbThis.ActiveSheet.Name, 4) = "User" Then

    ToggleCut True
    TogglePaste True

Else

    ToggleCut False
    TogglePaste False

    If .CutCopyMode = xlCut Then .CutCopyMode = False

End If

Here's the relevant excerpt from the 'TogglePaste' procedure (the NotifyFunctionDisabled procedure just uses the string passed in to build the message text in a MsgBox displayed to the user):
Public Sub TogglePaste(ByVal blAllow As Boolean)

    Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled

    Dim strFunction As String
    strFunction = "Paste"

    With Application

        Select Case blAllow
    
            Case Is = False
    
                .OnKey "^v", "'NotifyFunctionDisabled """ & strFunction & """'"
                .OnKey "+{INSERT}", "'NotifyFunctionDisabled """ & strFunction & """'"
    
            Case Is = True
    
                .OnKey "^v"
                .OnKey "+{INSERT}"
    
        End Select

    End With

End Sub

This setup works perfectly when the file is opened from the user's machine. The NotifyFunctionDisabled procedure, and the strFunction parameter, are associated with the keyboard shortcut and produce the desired MsgBox when the user tries to use Ctrl + X or Ctrl + V.
But when the file is opened from Sharepoint Online using the three-dots menu and 'Open in app', the exact same code seems not to register the association with the procedure call.
Has anybody else encountered this? Any ideas on a workaround, or do you think this is a bug in MS365?

The problem was the "...[long chain of subdirectories to file]...". It was so long that the fully-qualified path to the workbook and procedure name was truncated, it lopped off the name of the procedure in the error message.
I put a copy of the file into an ancestor directory on Sharepoint Online, so that the chain of subdirectories in the FQ path was much shorter, and it worked fine again.

Yeah, SharePoint "allows" 400 characters in a file path, but Excel VBA doesn't .....
